# Windows 10 USB tethering to Wifi via iPhone?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, usb, iphone

I have a Windows 10 PC without a network interface card that I want to connect to my home wifi. Is there any way to use my iPhone (ios 15.2.1) and a USB cable to connect my PC to wifi via the phone? I don't want to jailbreak my phone.

Googling only gives me Android tutorials and iPhone hotspot tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Apple says this is possible, are you having trouble getting it to work?
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/share-your-internet-connection-iph45447ca6/ios
[image]